# double click jar file

Tags: jar, executable-jar, double-click

I have created a swing program that displays a gui and takes user data from the respective gui. The program works fine when I am running it from eclipse. But the problem is that when I make an executable jar file and double click it nothing happens. Even if I run the jar file from console nothing happens and exception occurs. I am using scheduler and for that I am using a `quartz.jar` file. I guess the problem is not there.

The exceptions are shown below...

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/quartz/Job
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.quartz.Job
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 29 more
```

I have added the main class in `manifest.mf` file, but no success.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: How do you build your executable jar ?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go: File -> Export -> Java - JAR file, on the next screen check "Export java source files and resources"

or

read this link for command line executable jar conversion

http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-make-an-executable-jar-file/

or 
if u want to convert windows exe use this tool   Launch4J [http://sourceforge.net/projects/launch4j/]

Answer (score 0):

Check your manifest.mf
after 
Main-Class: YourClassHere

should be end with a new line or carriage return

[Warning: The text file must end with a new line or carriage return. The last line will not be parsed properly if it does not end with a new line or carriage return.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html)